# iOS14 - ViewHierarchy changes do prevent UIView extension to work

Tags: swift, uiview, hierarchy, nslayoutconstraint, stackview

Using iOS14.0.1, Xcode12.0.1 and Swift5.3,

With iOS14, the following UIView-extension no longer works properly:

```
@discardableResult
func anchor(top: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, leading: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, bottom: NSLayoutYAxisAnchor?, trailing: NSLayoutXAxisAnchor?, padding: UIEdgeInsets = .zero, size: CGSize = .zero) -> AnchoredConstraints {
    
    translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    var anchoredConstraints = AnchoredConstraints()
    
    if let top = top {
        anchoredConstraints.top = topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: top, constant: padding.top)
    }
    
    if let leading = leading {
        anchoredConstraints.leading = leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leading, constant: padding.left)
    }
    
    if let bottom = bottom {
        anchoredConstraints.bottom = bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottom, constant: -padding.bottom)
    }
    
    if let trailing = trailing {
        anchoredConstraints.trailing = trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailing, constant: -padding.right)
    }
    
    if size.width != 0 {
        anchoredConstraints.width = widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.width)
    }
    
    if size.height != 0 {
        anchoredConstraints.height = heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height)
    }
    
    [anchoredConstraints.top, anchoredConstraints.leading, anchoredConstraints.bottom, anchoredConstraints.trailing, anchoredConstraints.width, anchoredConstraints.height].forEach{ $0?.isActive = true }
    
    return anchoredConstraints
}
```

I only observe the problem since iOS14 release. Before, with iOS12 and iOS13 I never had a problem and I did use this extension a lot.

But now with iOS14 it leads to problems with UIControls no longer working.

Therefore, if I use the extension and do the following - then any UIControls in my ViewHierarchy do not work (i.e. no target-actions, switch-didChanges, etc will no longer kick-in)

```
SettingsStackView.anchor(top: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: contentView.leadingAnchor, bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor, trailing: contentView.trailingAnchor)
```

However, if I do it without the UIView-extension, then everything works fine:

```
SettingsStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
SettingsStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
SettingsStackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
SettingsStackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
SettingsStackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
```

See [my other example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64201017/3826232) where I describe the problem with more Code.

Can anybody tell me why the above UIView-extension is the root-cause of UIControls no longer reacting to touch events when used to constrain layout-constraints in code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a typo in the code you're showing...

Your code line using your `.anchor` function is:

```
SettingsStackView.anchor(top: safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, leading: contentView.leadingAnchor, bottom: contentView.bottomAnchor, trailing: contentView.trailingAnchor)
```

but your code without that func is:

```
SettingsStackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

Note that the first line is using:

```
safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
```

and the second line is using:

```
contentView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor
```

Comment: oh man - you are good ! This was it!. The UIView-extension is still working - but I have to pay attention to take `contentView` for all anchors. I simply did not see that. However, it is still unclear to me why the anchor without "contentView" would work under iOS12 and iOS13 but not iOS14 ??